# How to skip children in jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

There is dynamically build  Html block with some elements having attribute input-readonly-container. I need to select elements which are not in sub input-readonly-container.

```
<div id='root' input-readonly-container>
    <input id='1' type="text" />
    <input id='2' type="text" />
    <input id='3' type="button" value="Btn"/>
    <div id="child1" input-readonly-container>
        <input id='5' type="text"/>
        <input id='6' type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
        <input id='7' type="text"/>
        <input id='8' type="text"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

In this sample I need to select only elements with Id 1,2,3,7,8. Child container with [input-readonly-container] and internal elements (5,6) should be skipped.

Selection should happen inside of context of root element.

```
var root=$('#root');
$('selectorHere', root);
```

and this should select only id=1,2,3,7,8.

If child doesn't have [input-readonly-container], selection should pick all children elements (7,8)

If I run same selector with root=$('#child'), it should select id=5,6 only

So idea of selector to select elements of container with [input-readonly-container] which are not children of another element with attribute [input-readonly-container]

Comment: `id`s should not start with numbers

Comment: it is just sample - pseudo code. thanks though..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
jQuery('div[input-readonly-container]:first').children().not('[input-readonly-container]')
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("div[input-readonly-container]:first > input")`

You can use descendant selector to avoid grand child elements.

`:first` to select document's first element div containing attribute `input-readonly-only`

`> input` to select only descendants within div:first.

Comment: "You can use descendant selector to avoid grand child elements." That's the opposite of what descendant means...

Comment: "> input to select only descendants within div:first." Yeah you definitely have it backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the elements you want to select with jQuery and use a single selector in your Script.

```
<div input-readonly-container>
<input id='1' type="text" class="jquery-selector"/>
<input id='2' type="text" class="jquery-selector"/>
<input id='3' type="button" value="Btn" class="jquery-selector"/>
    <div id="child">
        <input id='5' type="text"/>
        <input id='6' type="text"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code

```
var listItems = jQuery('.jquery-selector');
```

Also its not good practice to start id's with numbers.

Try to keep code as simple and easy to read as possible.

Comment: it may work too, but answer from jedifans is exactly what I need. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Filter the childrens of the div, See the js fiddle here,
    https://jsfiddle.net/rahulpandey034/xot37hrd/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div[input-readonly-container]:first > input").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
});
```